# 403 error (Laravel + nginx + centos7) alibaba ecs

Tags: php, laravel, nginx, centos

Trying to host my laravel website onto an Alibaba ECS framework through the use of nginx, however i keep encoutering the error 403 where the directory permission is forbidden.

I have tried

```
1) chmod o+x /usr/share/nginx/html/laravel
2) chown -R root:root /usr/share/nginx/html/laravel
3) chmod -R 777 /usr/share/nginx/html/laravel
```

All to no avail

Can someone please tell me what i am doing wrongly... thank you!

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  -IP ADDRESS-;

    root   /usr/share/nginx/html/laravel;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
    error_page 404 /404.html;
    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;

    location = /50x.html {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html/laravel;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

Directory Permission path

```
[root@directory laravel]# namei -om /usr/share/nginx/html/laravel
f: /usr/share/nginx/html/laravel
 drwxr-xr-x root root /
 drwxr-xr-x root root usr
 drwxr-xr-x nginx nginx share
 drwxr-xr-x nginx nginx nginx
 drwxr-xr-x nginx nginx html
 drwxr-xr-x nginx nginx laravel
```

Error Message

```
2021/04/27 19:15:50 [error] 23810#0: *1 directory index of "/usr/share/nginx/html/laravel/" is forbidden, client: IP ADDRESS, server: IP ADDRESS, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "IP ADDRESS"
```

Comment: make sure `IP ADDRESS` is your public IP of server

Comment: @kamlesh paul it is for sure

Comment: Don't you have to point to public directory? Laravel root directory is wrong.

Comment: @Jack i have added in the /public directory but it is now just saying error 404 failed to load resource fav icon not found

Comment: then add favicon correctly :) maybe with {{asset('some/path/to/favicon.ico')}}